# How can I tell whether a Japanese company's name is in hiragana or katakana?

Tags: culture

So today in class, I actually learned that the Japanese game company "Sega"'s name is actually written in Katakana, not Hiragana.  I learned the same also applies to some other notable companies, such as Toyota and Honda. But it seems there are also companies that don't have katakana names, such as Mitsubishi.

Is there any way to tell right off the bat whether or not a Japanese company's name is in hiragana or katakana?    When I asked my teacher, she mentioned it might have something to do with how famous or popular the company may have been.

Comment: Look it up? Sega is apparently derived from the English "service games" so it wouldn't really make sense for it to be hiragana. If it's a foreign word it's probably going to be katakana.

Comment: There is no rule - best to check wikipedia or the company website.

Comment: My sensei also mentioned that fact that some company names use Katakana because it makes them "cooler", rather than  using so-called "clunky" hiragana.  Is this true?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no rule. Just like how company names in English can be in all-capitals (e.g. DKNY) or all small-letters (e.g. fcuk), I think it just has to do with how the company wants to present itself.  On a related note, I was surprised that that Nissan(日産) and Hitachi(日立) were actually written in Kanji.

Comment: Plenty of companies have their names all in katakana. I can think of ヨドバシカメラ as an immediate example of this

Comment: Companies generally choose names that are recognizeable/will stand out, and katakana is just another way to do this. In general, katakana is associated with cool foreign words/buzz words. It's a stylistic choice.

Comment: Actually, there is a rule. Trade Name Law defines the details. But the basic rule is you can choose the name whatever you like. ( Unless...things are defined in 会社法｛かいしゃほう｝etc. The notable Hiragana company is such as ひまわりホールディングズ。[link](http://www.himawari-group.co.jp/).

Comment: @user4060 You are right.みらいホールディングズ[link](https://www.miraihd.jp/company/) would've thought using Hiragana would be better.

Comment: Here[link](http://toyokeizai.net/articles/-/108954) is the list of company names that exist in Japan. As most people say, until 500th, I could only find 6 Hiragana companies and others are often with Karakana. ( Scroll down and click 1,2,3,4...)

Answer (score 3):

You can't not tell them Hiragana or Katakana.
Because they are desided arbitrarily　by companies.

I think using Hiragana as a company's name impress a bit childish and soft.
Because in old times, Hiragana was used for private documents especially by women.
And formal documents were written in Kanji.

Maybe by that historical reason, I feel a company's name in Kanji has a classical and steady atmosphere.

Naming a company in Katakana is relatively new culture.
Words which named in Katakana mostly have been imported with new things and knowredge from foreign counties.
That's why Katakana has images of something new and western and cool.

We still worship western culture unconsciously.

Comment: It seems that you are claiming that the use of katakana in company names is a result of unconscious worship of western culture, but this claim is quite misleading.  Note that the practice of reserving katakana for loanwords _is_ a new thing.  (I think that it was established after World War II.)  Some companies such as Toyota Motor Corp. used katakana in their company names before this practice was established.

Comment: Even before WWII, katakana was used rather than hiragana in hiragana-kanji text (not katakana-kanji text) to mark loanwords.

Comment: Oh please,I never said "after WWII" and just said "relatively new culture."
I said "We still worship western culture unconsiously(actually very cousiously)" and I want to explain that.
Please see below one.
http://matome.naver.jp/odai/2128702310428498001
There are many antique posters with their ages.
Some of them like "サッポロビール" are very interesting.
"ビール" is of course loanword, and "サッポロ" isn't.But their 2 words are given same treatment.
Their commercial posters suggested new life style with prodacts of western origin in "Katakana" and introduced company's name in "Katakana" too.

Comment: Here,katakana is not only a phonogram,but also cool western symbol.
Many western culture and words continue to be imported in "Katakana" as cool symbol even now.
We feel Katakana words are cool,that means,we longed for western.
Although maybe there are other reasons like to give them an impression of global company,I think "worship" is one big reason of applying Katakana to company's names.

Comment: The phrase “relatively new” is misleading because what you claimed to be “relatively new culture” actually dates back older than the practice of reserving katakana for loanwords.  Today many company names use katakana for stylistic effects (including the effect to look like loanwords), but if you write history, please write the correct history.

Comment: OK.I recognized what I said was misleading like you said.I shouldn't have use an ambiguous phrase "relatively new culture",and I want you to permit to rephrase "after the Meiji Restoration" by it.And then,are there other incorrect descriptions historically?By the way,I want to hear your opinion when was the start of naming them in katakana without ambiguous phrases like"older than".The source of my argument is here,just wikipedia...http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%AE%E8%80%81%E8%88%97%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7